# How do I correct the following sentence, "When I was speeding out of control I couldn't brake" (ice skating)?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

I was told that I shouldn't use the verb brake when I'm talking about ice skates. However, I'm not sure what an appropriate substitute would be (I can't find a similar verb that conveys an equal message). Does a verb exist so that it doesn't change the format of the sentence?

Comment: Is "stop" not good enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common term is to *stop*. For examples of how it is used, see [How to stop while ice skating?](https://www.myactivesg.com/Sports/Ice-Skating/Training-Method/Ice-Skating-for-Beginners/How-do-I-stop-while-ice-skating)

Comment: Would using the term "stop" still imply the use of a technique to do so? Would the listener be able to tell that the speaker means he is unable to employ the proper technique to stop or just that he or she is completely incapable of stopping no matter what?

Comment: As you can see in the reference, there are multiple techniques. If the speaker means he is unable to use a specific technique he could say something like "I am unable to do the T-stop". If someone says "I couldn't stop" I would assume he couldn't use any proper technique (but I would also assume he did eventually **stop**, in the broader sense of the word, by hitting the board or something worse...)

Answer (score -1):

"[Brake](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/brake)" can mean either "[slow down](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/slow-down)" or "stop".